# How to check if a track is added/deleted from library/playlist

Tags: javascript, api, spotify

I'm building an album view for a playlist. When someone adds or removes a track from the playlist I want to catch that event and reload the view.

How do I catch this event?

I've logged m.EVENT and found the 'ITEMS_ADDED', 'ITEMS_MOVED' and 'ITEMS_REMOVED' events, but can't seem to get it working.

Comment: Do you have any code to show what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using the latest preview build available here, which fixes a few event bugs.

http://developer.spotify.com/en/spotify-apps-api/preview/

... and documentation here:

http://developer.spotify.com/download/spotify-apps-api/preview/reference/

Check the Playlist page for an example.